# autonum does not like \ref in a \caption

Tags: captions, labels, autonum

The following is a minimal non-working example of a reference to some label within a caption while using the [autonum package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/autonum).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{autonum}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    E = mc^2 \label{eq::label}
\end{align}

\begin{figure}
    y \caption{ \ref{eq::label} }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Upon compiling I get the following errors:

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
! Paragraph ended before \@caption was complete.
```

I get the same result, if I refer to, say another figure, instead of an equation.

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\protect`

```
\caption{\protect\ref{eq::label}}
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the problem. I just uploaded version 0.3.2 which contains the fix. So the user supplied `\protect` is not needed with that version anymore. It may take some time until 0.3.2 has propagated via CTAN.